# Transport a row to sheet2 on the occurrence of the variable X

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

So, So, I am trying to transfer from Sheet1 to Sheet2 every row that contains the value 'other' in column X

```
I tried with the formula
=query('Sheet1'!A1:Z1000, "where X contains 'other'")
```

For the first row that has such characteristics the formula works, but on the second one an error for overwrite occurs.
What might be the best solution that would allow me to transfer as many rows as possible with the characteristics expressed in the introduction?

Comment: can you paste/screenshot that error? or share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> We have "column X" containing in some cases "Other" like this.

[image]

> We need to get data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 only if "column X" have the value "Other", **Paste** this formula in Sheet2 Cell `A1`

```
={ Sheet1!A1:W1 ; FILTER(Sheet1!A1:W,Sheet1!X1:X="Other")}
```

[image]

---

> **Source & output view**

[image]